# Client non-responding on official email but talks only on skype

Tags: contracts, communication, difficult-client, payments

I just had a project that was like bad dream - finally we settled for a refund amount. Along with the same, client also allowed me to have complete control over my code.

The problem is, above agreement happened over skype.

To put things into perspective, I emailed summary of our agreement from my email to his official email ID. And asked him for his bank details so that I could process refund for him.

In response, he provided the needed info over skype, again, instead of choosing to respond to my email.

I am worried:

- I announced my obligation to pay him his refund amount, via email, but he didn't respond to it.
- He rather chose skype to provide the bank details for the refund amount
- In the process, he completely ignored the code ownership part that we had agreed upon over skype (and refund was settled based on the same)

His company is registered in USA.

Does not replying mean agreement in USA?

Or should I wait till he nods his (email) confirmation to my summary in the email, before I pay him the refund?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is **nothing** wrong with explaining to a client that Skype (or phone calls) are not sufficient and you need to have **written** approval of something either via email, fax, or postal mail.

I would wait until you have a clear, written, approval of terms.

Comment: Not "approval", Scott.  Agreement.  Approval equates to authorization, which is is a bit one sided.  It matters.